# ERROR: ARRAY is missing type definition for its values Sequelize

Tags: arrays, sql-server, database, migration, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run the command to create the migration on sequelize, on my SQL Server database, and I get the following error:

> ERROR: ARRAY is missing type definition for its values

In the js file that was created is the definition:

```
images: {
   type: Sequelize.ARRAY
}
```

Comment: As the error message suggests it needs to be an array of something. e.g.: `Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)` Also array types are only supported on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 17):

After having the same problem myself, I've solved it by changing both model and migration files.
They should be like this:

**migration file:**

```
images: {
     type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER)
}
```

**model file:**

```
images: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)
```